# Android WebView Capture & Upload Video & Image with camera & from storage

Tags: java, android, android-webview, video-capture, android-camera-intent

I am trying to upload images & videos to a webView from camera and from storage.
Previously it was working for uploading images and capturing photos from the device with the code below. I made some changes to support video uploading as well but it didn't work so I unchanged it. But now uploading captured image is also not working. Only uploading image files is working with the code mentioned below.

**I want to upload videos & images both from storage as well as camera and camcorder of the device. What changes should I make in the below code?**

```
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    // Create an image file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File imageFile = File.createTempFile(
            imageFileName,  /* prefix */
            ".jpg",         /* suffix */
            storageDir      /* directory */
    );
    return imageFile;
}

public class PQChromeClient extends WebChromeClient {

    // For Android 5.0
    public boolean onShowFileChooser(WebView view, ValueCallback<Uri[]> filePath, WebChromeClient.FileChooserParams fileChooserParams) {
        // Double check that we don't have any existing callbacks
        if (mFilePathCallback != null) {
            mFilePathCallback.onReceiveValue(null);
        }
        mFilePathCallback = filePath;

        Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            // Create the File where the photo should go
            File photoFile = null;
            try {
                photoFile = createImageFile();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra("PhotoPath", mCameraPhotoPath);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                // Error occurred while creating the File
                Log.e(TAG, "Unable to create Image File", ex);
            }

            // Continue only if the File was successfully created
            if (photoFile != null) {
                mCameraPhotoPath = "file:" + photoFile.getAbsolutePath();
                takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT,
                        Uri.fromFile(photoFile));
            } else {
                takePictureIntent = null;
            }
        }

        Intent contentSelectionIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        contentSelectionIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        contentSelectionIntent.setType("image/*");

        Intent[] intentArray;
        if (takePictureIntent != null) {
            intentArray = new Intent[]{takePictureIntent};
        } else {
            intentArray = new Intent[0];
        }

        Intent chooserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CHOOSER);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INTENT, contentSelectionIntent);
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TITLE, "Image Chooser");
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, intentArray);

        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, INPUT_FILE_REQUEST_CODE);

        return true;

    }

    // openFileChooser for Android 3.0+
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg, String acceptType) {

        mUploadMessage = uploadMsg;
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
        // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard

        File imageStorageDir = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                        Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                , "AndroidExampleFolder");

        if (!imageStorageDir.exists()) {
            // Create AndroidExampleFolder at sdcard
            imageStorageDir.mkdirs();
        }

        // Create camera captured image file path and name
        File file = new File(
                imageStorageDir + File.separator + "IMG_"
                        + String.valueOf(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        + ".jpg");

        mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);

        // Camera capture image intent
        final Intent captureIntent = new Intent(
                android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

        captureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);

        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE);
        i.setType("image/*");

        // Create file chooser intent
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(i, "Image Chooser");

        // Set camera intent to file chooser
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS
                , new Parcelable[] { captureIntent });

        // On select image call onActivityResult method of activity
        startActivityForResult(chooserIntent, FILECHOOSER_RESULTCODE);


    }

    // openFileChooser for Android < 3.0
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg) {
        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, "");
    }

    //openFileChooser for other Android versions
    public void openFileChooser(ValueCallback<Uri> uploadMsg,
                                String acceptType,
                                String capture) {

        openFileChooser(uploadMsg, acceptType);
    }

}
```